# right frozen column in richfaces extended datatable

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, richdatatable

The [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky) demostrates the **frozen column** feature on the **left hand side** of the table (columns vendor+Model).

But...can I have **frozen columns** on the **right side** as well?

My richfaces library version is 4.3.

I already investigated in the renderer code. AFAIK there are no preparations for such a feature, so is there an alternative/workaround/future plans?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is have two separate tables. You can switch the two halves with jQuery but it will mess with the resizability (the same happens with `direction: rtl`).